# expand full path in bash prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to have bash always print the full path, rather than using ~ to denote the user's home folder. My desire here may be unusual, but the question pertains to anybody who wants a fully custom prompt that can change significantly between commands.  I have found a way to do it, but it's not foolproof:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1=`echo -n $PWD \#`'
```

what this does is re-write the prompt every time a new command is executed.  90% of the time it works great. But sometimes, when the prompt is shown, my cursor is placed at the start of the line, rather than at the end, so that my typing overwrites the prompt. What's going on ?!? How do I get the cursor to always start after the # in the prompt in this example?

Comment: Questions about end-user configuration belong on [unix.se]. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_.

Comment: Just do `PS1='$(pwd)\$ '` or `PS1='$PWD\$ '`

Comment: Depending on your distro, you should just be able to remove `export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3` from either your bashrc or the system file. (ditto on Unix & Linux)

Comment: That said, a few notes: A command substitution is basically always the wrong thing. It's literally at least an order of magnitude faster if your code is written as `PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="$PWD #"'`, but why use a `PROMPT_COMMAND` at all when you can just put `$PWD` is your PS1 directly?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, `$(pwd)` is a huge performance hit to eat. Why recommend anything that spawns a subshell when there's a built-in variable that will evaluate to the same value?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is, but as stated in the question the user may want a "fully custom prompt", and often a process substitution is the only way to get the desired customization.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...sure, there might be conceivable circumstances where it's necessary, but `$(pwd)` is not an example of same.

Comment: The real question here is: why the abuse of `PROMPT_COMMAND`?  There's no need for that.

Comment: @AlRo, ...another thing to keep in mind that any literal value in PS1 is going to be interpreted with all the rules that normally apply, even if that value comes from a filename. Which is part of why using `PROMPT_COMMAND` here is a bad idea: When you have code that writes to PS1, that code needs to be responsible for making sure the values are escaped to not have unintended meaning, and that's not logic that's easy to fit into a one-liner when you're injecting values from dynamically-changing state.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so that's also going to apply PS1='$(pwd)\$ ' or is that properly escaped?

Comment: @AlRo : It's not wrong, but you create a child process unnecessarily. The only advantage over using `$PWD` instead is, that if you in an attack of madness decide to manually change `PWD` on the command line, the bogus value will be in your prompt until the next `cd ....` or `pushd ....` command fixes it. Since nobody plans to modify `PWD` anyway, the perils of this are low.

Comment: @AlRo, because `PS1='$PWD'` has the body in _single quotes_, it's all literal content -- the content of PWD isn't substituted in yet when PS1 is being scanned for prompt-specific syntax. Whereas `PS1="$PWD"` would have the problem. Same applies for `$(pwd)` in single or double quotes (but, as user1934428 says, using `$(pwd)` is slower to execute than `$PWD`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3 doesn't prevent the home dir to ~ substitution I'm explicitly asking for here, at least on the two Debian variants I tried it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply do a

```
PS1='$PWD #'
```

instead of fiddling with `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Using single quotes is crucial here, since you want the variable to be evaluated by the time the prompt is generated.

Comment: I misunderstood this. I will update my answer.

Comment: This nicely produces the exact thing I was looking for, though it doesn't address the wider issue of programmatically generating a prompt after each command line invocation.

Comment: My suggestion can be generalzed. For instance if you want to recalculate a completely new prompt every time, I would then write a program (shell script), say `$HOME/bin/make_prompt_string`, which writes to stdout a prompt string, and then set `PS1='$($HOME/bin/make_prompt_string)'`.

Comment: is that really better? an extra shell script and shell invocation instead of just using PROMPT_COMMAND which seems to be intended for this purpose. My mistake seems to be primarily not properly escaping the part where I set the new value of PS1. I do like your answer for the simple case of just using $PWD though.

Comment: You need a command - be it a shell script or a function - only if you have to do complex work. In this case, it is true that `PROMPT_COMMAND` spares you from having a child process invoked (provided that you implement it as a function), though I don't see a real performance impact from having a child process in this context. The difference is more in maintainability, and hence more a matter of taste than of complexity. From the viewpoint of peformance, both approaches should be roughly the same.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried your exact method (copy and paste, so there's no typos) and I'm still having the problem that sometimes bash places the cursor at the start of the line, rather than at the end of the prompt. I can't tell why exactly, but one time it consistently does it is when I log in.